# How to check if a column in TableView is PrimaryKey(ResultSet) and make the cells not editable

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

How is possible to check if a column taken using ResultSet is a primary or not and if it a Primary than to make cells of this column not editable.Im using JavaFX.

Im using this code but it doesn't work...Thank you!

```
 ObservableList<String> column = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet();
    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
    tblTable.getColumns().clear();
    ResultSet cols = meta.getColumns(comboDatabase.getValue(), null, cmbTable.getValue(), null);
    ResultSet pk = meta.getPrimaryKeys(comboDatabase.getValue(), null,cmbTable.getValue());
        while (pk.next()) {
        String primarykey = pk.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        set.add(primarykey);
        }
    while (cols.next()) {
    String name = cols.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
    TableColumn col = new TableColumn(name);
    column.add(name);
    tblTable.getColumns().addAll(col);
  
    
      if(set.contains(column)){
    col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    col.setEditable(false);
    tblTable.setEditable(true);
          System.out.println("1");
    }else{
      col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    col.setEditable(true);
    tblTable.setEditable(true);
    System.out.println("2");
      }
```

Comment: Please use the formatting features of your IDE to [format your code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html).  Link is just an example use the appropriate function for your IDE.

Comment: Surely you mean `if (set.contains(name))` ???